Will Android allow an app to run 24/7 using PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, or will it eventually kill the process?
I need to write an Android app that operates continuously in all modes (foreground, background, and screen-off), maintains stable server communication (basically web page opened which does something in the background).
I want to use PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK with periodic renewal of the lock with turned off battery optimization for app.
I need to use Rust + Tauri framework for UI.
So, my question is, will it work, or will Android kill this process after some time? Maybe there are other caveats that I need to be aware of?

Is this app running on hardware with your own custom firmware build on it? If not, device manufacturers may affect your process, above and beyond what Android itself might do.

I made a couple of edits to make the question easier to find and understand for people who are likely to know the answer (or want to know the answer), hopefully the edits are ok.

There is nothing that will make an app work that way, unless you have a custom version of Android.  Luckily you probably don't actually need this or really want it.  There are better ways to structure your app.  Explain what you're actually trying to do int he background and we can try to suggest them.

@GabeSechan I understand this, but my task is to create such app. Client wants application with opened web page. On this page using wgpu server would perform something.

Even if you run it in foreground service with wakelocks, all battery optimizations disabled AND engage the user in activity daily you'd still have issues keeping up a never-ending process on modern android versions.

@NYBACHOK your job as an engineer isn't to do what the client tells you.  It's to figure out what they really want and need.  For example, they want the app to be constantly up to date.  They describe that as "always running and talking to the server".  What they really need is push messaging so they don't need to always be running.  Figuring out things like that is part of the job

@GabeSechan I know this. Maybe I was unclear in my task and why locking phone is the only way I see. Phone will be used for distributed computing. Example is cryptocurrencies mining...
